# What evidence is there that the Babylonians used the Babylonain method of estimating square roots?

Tags: mathematics, ancient

The Babylonian method for computing square roots is described (among other places) in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method).  What evidence is there that they actually used this method?

I have found several references that imply that they did *not* use an iterative process, but used a closely related method that stopped after a single iteration (see, for instance, [Square  Root  Approximations  in  Old  Babylonian  Mathematics: YBC  7289  in  Context](https://math.berkeley.edu/~lpachter/128a/Babylonian_sqrt2.pdf), and the [Wikipedia notes for Square Root of 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#cite_note-1), Note 1).

Yet other references imply that they indeed used the iterative process.  In his *A History of Mathematics*, C. Boyer happily explains the iterative process (which I find unusual because every other sentence in C. Boyer's works usually reads something like, "...but it would be foolish to assume that these ancient mathematicians had any idea what they were doing..."...but I digress).

Going back to the Yale tablet YBC 7289, the Babylonians evidently knew $\sqrt{2}$ to six decimal places. Is it safe to assume they *did* have an iterative process, based on this and other circumstantial evidence?

Comment: Your Fowler-Robson reference pretty much answers your question on p. 376:"*Both of these alternatives remain conjectural, however, as there is still no direct evidence — by which we mean explicit instructions in the course of a mathematical
solution — for the use of more than the first step of the procedure*". There is no need to assume they were aware of "iterative process". Someone made a first estimate using the procedure once, a century later someone else applied the same procedure to the first estimate and got a more precise value, which was then put into tables.

Comment: Roger that.  I was curious if I had missed any other important references.  The Fowler-Robson paper seems to be the most legit analysis I've found (and one that other sites/papers reference) so I'll stick with that.